# internet share in 2nd ethernet port of ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: server, 16.04, ip, router

I have a server pc which is running on ubuntu server 16.04
this server has two ethernet port - `eno1` and `eno2`. I'm using my `eno1` port to access internet using following code in `interfaces` file located in `/etc/network/`

```
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
address 103.56.4.162
netmask 255.255.255.248
gateway 103.56.4.161
dns-nameservers 103.56.4.6 8.8.8.8
```

I can access internet, no problem.

what I want is to share that internet to `eno2` and I want to connect my router from this `eno2` ethernet port.

How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how to do that. after many try I found the solution. I got this solution from this link 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Router

First thing first, don't forget to backup your interfaces file before edit it

```
sudo cp /etc/network/interfaces /etc/network/interfaces.bak
```

for `eno2` I have append bellow lines to above interfaces file

```
auto eno2
iface eno2 inet static
address 192.168.0.1
network 192.168.0.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
```

Than I created a script file called `nat.sh` and put bellow code:

```
echo -e "\n\nLoading simple rc.firewall-iptables version $FWVER..\n"
DEPMOD=/sbin/depmod
MODPROBE=/sbin/modprobe

EXTIF="eno1"
INTIF="eno2"

echo "   External Interface:  $EXTIF"
echo "   Internal Interface:  $INTIF"

#======================================================================
#== No editing beyond this line is required for initial MASQ testing == 
echo -en "   loading modules: "
echo "  - Verifying that all kernel modules are ok"
$DEPMOD -a
echo "----------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo -en "ip_tables, "
$MODPROBE ip_tables
echo -en "nf_conntrack, " 
$MODPROBE nf_conntrack
echo -en "nf_conntrack_ftp, " 
$MODPROBE nf_conntrack_ftp
echo -en "nf_conntrack_irc, " 
$MODPROBE nf_conntrack_irc
echo -en "iptable_nat, "
$MODPROBE iptable_nat
echo -en "nf_nat_ftp, "
$MODPROBE nf_nat_ftp
echo "----------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo -e "   Done loading modules.\n"
echo "   Enabling forwarding.."
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
echo "   Enabling DynamicAddr.."
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_dynaddr 
echo "   Clearing any existing rules and setting default policy.."

iptables-restore <<-EOF
*nat
-A POSTROUTING -o "$EXTIF" -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A FORWARD -i "$EXTIF" -o "$INTIF" -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -i "$INTIF" -o "$EXTIF" -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j LOG
COMMIT
EOF

echo -e "\nrc.firewall-iptables v$FWVER done.\n"
```

than I make it executable by doing

```
chmod a+x nat.sh
```

than run it as root

```
sudo sh nat.sh
```

make our new script bootable so we don't have to run the script every time we restart.

```
sudo cp nat.sh /etc/init.d/
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/nat.sh /etc/rc2.d/S95masquradescript
```

Than I plugged my ethernet cable which is connected to router to `eno2` and configured my router for static ip as bellow for DHCP:

```
IP Address: 192.168.0.2
Netmask: 255.255.255.0 (/24)
Gateway: 192.168.0.1
DNS Server: 103.56.4.6
            8.8.8.8
```

and it worked for me.